# Remove all non-numbers characters from filename

Tags: command-line

I have a file called `042dasd|.txt`, and I want to remove all the non-numbers characters from it's name, so the output will be `042.txt`. By the way, how can I do that for many files? I tried using regex but I think that I'm not in the right way.

```
$ mv 042dasd|.txt # to 042.txt
```

And for many files example

```
mv *.txt # remove all numbers from file names
```

Comment: Try `${filename//[^0-9]/}` for new file name.

Comment: With what to replace the `filename`? Can you answer please to my second question (rename all files in cwd to be without non-numeric chars)?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute/remove all non-digit up to the last dot.

```
$ rename -n 's/[^0-9](?![^.]*$)//g' *[0-9]*.txt
```

<sup>Remove -n then you feel safe to  take action.</sup>

Comment: It will not take any action on filenames without digits.

Answer (score 0):

If the `rename` command is not installed in your system or you do not want to use it, the following *bash* script can be used as an alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.* ; do
  ext="${f##*.}"
  bfn="${f%.*}"
  nfn="${bfn//[^0-9]/}"
  echo mv "$f" "$nfn.$ext"
done
```

The `for` loop is used to execute the code for each file that matches the pattern `*.*`. You can change the `*.*` pattern to something more appropriate for you; e.g., `*.txt`.

The line `ext="${f##*.}"` will extract the extension of the file name (the text after the *last* `.`). In your example file name, it will be something like `txt`. Note: If the file name does not contain an extension, this script may not work the way you want it. Try it and see.

The line `bfn="${f%.*}"` will extract the base name of the file, by stripping the last `.` and anything following it.

The line `nfn="${bfn//[^0-9]/}"` will remove all non-numeric characters from the base name of the file.

The line `echo mv "$f" "$nfn.$ext"` will display the *move* commands that should be executed. If you are satisfied with the output, remove the `echo` command, to run the actual `mv` commands.